# Install from web tab fails installation

Tags: plugin, installation

Install from Web tab initially returned a blank page in both Firefox and Chrome. I disabled then uninstalled plugin. When I click on "Add Install from Web" button, I get the following:

> Error connecting to the server: Could not resolve host:
>   s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com

Running Joomla! 3.9.12 with a bunch of addon extensions, but this error doesn't look like an extension-conflict error. 
Thanks, 
Kate

Comment: Have you checked the JED website isn't down?

Comment: Did you reinstall the plugin? Without the plugin the button appears but does nothing when I click it. If I reinstall the plugin from here, https://downloads.joomla.org/extensions/install-from-web/2-0-1 , then the plugin is enabled, the button goes away and I get a successful connection and display.